# Why did Nebraska ratify the Twenty-seventh Amendment 24 years after it came into force?

Tags: united-states, constitution, amendment

The [Twenty-seventh Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-seventh_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) came into force in 1992 after enough states ratified it. On April 1, 2016, Nebraska chose to ratify this amendment as well, despite it having been in force for 24 years.

Why did Nebraska decide to do this, especially since there really isn't any impact? Was it an [April Fools' Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day) joke? Or is there some purpose behind this that I am not seeing?

Comment: on the first reading of the wikipedia article, I had to re-read it. It looked to me as ...prohibits any law that increases or decreases the slavery of members of Congress from taking effect...  I have to clean my glasses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a tidy up. According to [this report](http://journalstar.com/legislature/it-took-awhile-but-add-nebraska-s-name-to-the/article_9ce8c67d-a7f6-5680-a63a-126e2d93bf61.html), Senator Laura Ebke stumbled on the omission while researching another resolution and decided to close the gap.

> "This is really a ceremonial thing," she said. "James Madison wrote this. It would be kind of neat to go ahead and have Nebraska ratify it."

Comment: Mississippi had a similar but more embarrassing omission re ratifying the amendment that ended slavery.